# Everything displaying as wireframe in fresh blend file

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, wireframe

I recently started up a new project and had not booted up blender in about 2-3 weeks so I'm unaware if any major update has happened or something, but no matter what I toggle my view to, everything seems off?[image]

This is what a fresh scene looks like right off boot, no settings have been altered, anything I add becomes this wireframe-esque object that becomes invisible if I de-select it. Any idea on what might be up?

Comment: The long and the short of it is that it's your AMD Adrenalin Drivers (latest version) causing the problem. Roll back to a previous driver version to fix the issue with blender.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you!

Comment: No Problem, It's a very common issue, hitting a lot of users recently.

Comment: Rolling back the drivers may help, but what you can do as well (without having to degrade the drivers) is to go to Render settings --> Performance --> High Quality normals and then enable it.